# Nhibernate GroupBy Count

Tags: nhibernate

Can't seem to find a solution to this. I have a QueryOver that has a grouping in it. I want to page the result, however, I can't seem to workout out a way to get the total number of rows.

```
var companies = session.QueryOver<Company>
                       .SelectList(list =>
                                   list
                                   .SelectGroup(x=> x.Domain).WithAlias(() => item.Text)
                                   .SelectCount(x=> x.Domain).WithAlias(() => item.Total));

companies.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ItemCount>());

var totalRows = companies.ToRowCountQuery();
```

Problem is that the "ToRowCountQuery()" removes the grouping. If I did

```
var list = companies.List<ItemCount>();
```

this would produce the following SQL

```
SELECT TOP (20 /* @p1 */) this_.Domain        as y0_,
             count(this_.Domain) as y1_
FROM   [Company] this_
GROUP  BY this_.Domain
ORDER  BY y1_ desc;
```

What I'm after it the following

```
select COUNT(*)
from (SELECT this_.Domain        as y0_,
             count(this_.Domain) as y1_
    FROM   [Company] this_
    GROUP  BY this_.Domain) g
```

I have searched the internet and can't find even a hit to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this already a few times on SO, but anyways, nhibernate does NOT support nested selects within the from clause.

Nested selects are supported only within the from and where under certain conditions, at least `QueryOver` does not have that many restrictions as the linq provider has.

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is, has anyone figured out a work around. At the moment I'm having to do a clone of the query, and get the full list back to get a count on that.

Comment: I mean you could query with native SQL instead of using the ORM, or call a stored procedure or something if you really need this particular thing. Otherwise maybe try to restructure your plain query to something which is supported in nhibernate? Maybe you can still achieve the same result somehow differently? Not sure ^^

Comment: I think that is the way that I will need to go, shame that NH does not support this